# solidity equivalent for new thread

Tags: solidity, blockchain, synchronization

I want to create a contract, which has a deposit function.

But I also want, in the constructor, to start a "thread" that polls an external data source (via oraclize/chainlink or similar) at certain frequency.

Or instead of setting up a loop, should I just call each new block ?

```
contract SimpleOraclizeContract is usingOraclize {

      
    function SimpleOraclizeContract() {
      // something like this in java
       new thread().run(new Runnable(){
         while(true){
            sleep(10);
            if(oraclize_getPrice() > 100) {
               doSomething();
            }
         }
     })
    }

    function updatePrice() payable {
        if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
        } else {
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
        }
    }
```

Given the above code how could I call oraclize_getPrice("URL") (which I assume is inherited) every for 10 seconds, or every new block ? Completely outside of a payable function.

Comment: the simple answer: you can't.

Comment: @MajdTL nice.  Any further info ?

Answer (score 1):

Smart contracts does not allow for security reason to call outside services.
You will not be able to start new threads, this feature does not exist.
Can you give more details about your needs to see how we can help you ?

Comment: I thought you could oraclize a call ?

Comment: Oracles "inject" your data into the smart contract from outside. Smart contracts are not able to call outside services.

Comment: OK, I will expand question

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible with smart contracts in this form.

- A contract cannot automatically run periodically. It has to be invoked by a transaction
- There are no threads in smart contracts, only single-thread synchronous execution
- A contract cannot interact with off-chain services (e.g. an API)

If you want to have some kind of off-chain values in your contract you have to provide them with a transaction.

```
contract USDPrice {
    address admin;
    uint price;

    constructor() public {
        admin = msg.sender;    
    }

    function setPrice(uint newPrice) external {
        require(admin == msg.sender, "only admin is allowed to set price");
        price = newPrice;
    }
}
```

Then you can make a piece of software (e.g. in Java) which queries the API you want to use for changes. If it detects a change it initiates a call to `setPrice` with the value.

Comment: Hi thanks. I get the single threaded idea. But I thought oraclize was for external api calls, and chainlink ?

Comment: In essence Chainlink works like this. Of course in reality there is a lot more involved - especially making sure that the correct values are supplied to the contract.

Comment: ok. But even without chainlink, oraclize can call an external api right ?

Comment: No. A smart contract can never directly call an API or anything outside the chain. It can only interact with other contracts during execution.